# How to open project from workspace in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I imported an Eclipse project into workspace and after some time I deleted it in Eclipse (from project explorer but not from workspace). Now, I want to reopen it, or import it again, but I cannot import it because such a project already exists in the workspace and when I try to open it, in tab `Project -> Open Project`, it is disabled. Of course, I can delete the project from workspace and import it again, but this is not what I want. So the question is: how can I open the project, which is in Eclipse's workspace, but has been deleted from the Eclipse's project explorer?

[image: check it out]

Comment: If you deleted the project only from eclipse, you should be able to import it by File->Import.

Comment: Yeah, I can read that and wrote the comment considering it. I just created a project, deleted it from eclipse without deleting the contents and re-imported as I said. Aren't you doing the same thing?

Comment: look at the screen I've uploaded :/ I am doing the same thing, but it doesn't work for me?:S

Comment: Why not just create a new workspace?

Comment: I can create that warning when I only close the project in Eclipse and try to reimport the project. Maybe your workspace is somehow broken, I'm not sure.

Comment: Tom 
I don't want to create a new workspace every time I reopen a Project.
suat
 I don't know if there is something wrong with my workspace, I downloaded Eclipse normally then Eclipse asked me where to create workspace - I think this is normal way of creating workspace.

Answer (score 13):

This is exactly what I just ran into. The 'Finish' button is greyed out, as is the check box and project name in the project window. If you try to check that check box the project will not be greyed now, but it won't check. Refresh does nothing.

The trick (or is it a bug) is to uncheck 'copy projects into workspace' hit the refresh button and it will now be checked and you can hit the finish button. Project will now once again be available in the Package Explorer.
(I'm using Eclipse 3.8 and ADT 21.0.1)

Answer (score 9):

These Steps You Have to Follow

1. Click File menu
2. In file menu click Import
3. A window is open Now click General Folder
4. Now click Existing project into workspace
5. Then click the select from root directory
6. Now import project which you want......

Comment: Choosing a general project import is the key instead of an Android project import.  It should obviously work with both import methods, but it does not.

Comment: Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace --> "Finish" button is grayed --> no way to open the project(s) ....

Answer (score 5):

You have to choose the project in the workspace, not the zip file with your project. Your project is still in your workspace, and because Eclipse wants to copy the project from the zip file you chose (look at the checked check box "Copy projects into workspace"), you get that warning.

Just select "Select root directory" and choose your workspace as your root directory and choose the project you want to reimport (and make sure, that the checkbox "Copy projects into workspace" is not checked).

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to “%ECLIPSE_HOME%\configuration.settings” and delete the workspace listed at the key RECENT_WORKSPACES
2. Restart Eclipse, go to File>Switch Workspace>Other… and select your workspace dir again
3. Now I could create new projects as always

Answer (score 0):

One simple trick is to delete the project from your work-space directory manually and than try to import project again. That's it...

Comment: Can you confirm what to delete? Is it enough to delete the `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resource/.projects/myProjectName` folder?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this same problem. It was a deleted workspace which I re-imported. When I tried to work with junit tests in the directory, it said that parts of if were not in the "project" In order to fix this, I had to check the "SEARCH FOR NESTED PROJECTS" and that corrected the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a really old question, possibly the solution was not available back then, but on my system (Eclipse Photon 4.8.0) it works like this:

1. File menu
2. Open Projects from File System...

Here you can give Eclipse a path to a directory (in this case your own, currently used workspace directory) where it will search for possible projects, list them and let you choose which one to import into the workspace. It will show already imported (aka. existing inside Eclipse) projects grayed out and unselectable, but has an option to hide these as well.
After selecting the project you'd like to import just click the Finish button and voila.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your project is included in current workspace, then you have to see the project under "Project Explorer".

Note: you can view this from: Window->Show View->Project Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

#### If you are facing this:

Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace --> "Finish" *button is grayed* --> *hence, no way to open the project(s)*

#### Solution:

1. Go to File -> Open File...
2. Choose any one file of your project, and the entire project folder will open in your present workspace.