# How to run spring boot project downloaded from GitHub

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I'm a beginner in Java spring boot having studied Java Core and J2EE. Previously I have been coding in PHP so now I want to learn web development in java spring boot. Before I proceed to commit myself to it, I want to know if I will be able to export my projects from one machine and continue with them on a different one. To check this, I downloaded a simple Hello World spring boot app from Github and tried to run it on my machine in Eclipse STS but it's not working. Is there a clearly outlined procedure of how to run any project from another machine or github?

Comment: Depending on artifact, you will have to install all the required dependencies with `mvn clean install` or download the dependency if it is just a java project. With `mvn spring-boot:run` you can run the proj

Answer (score 0):

You just need to import the project.

```
File --> Import... --> From Archive
```

[image]

Depending on the project, you may want to change the settings. For example, if a Database connection is required, you will find your settings in application.properties file: [image]

Comment: I have just tried to import through Archive File as you have highlighted but after I select my zip file, my Finish button is deactivated and the import wizard is showing this error: ' Cannot import into a workspace with no open projects. Please create a project before importing.'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14794371/8422732 try if this is the option for you.